# Is it possible to locate element by partial class match in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm getting starting with Selenium and I'm trying to locate the Next button on the cnn site and if it isn't the last page to click on it, otherwise to end the program.

The html code for enabled button is:

```
<div class="pagination-arrow pagination-arrow-right cnnSearchPageLink text-active">
    "Next"
 <i class="icon icon--arrow-right"></i>
</div>
```

The html code for disabled button is:

```
<div class="pagination-arrow pagination-arrow-right text-deactive">
    "Next"
 <i class="icon icon--arrow-right"></i>
</div>
```

How should approach the solution? I tried `is_enabled()` or to find part of  text in class name but didn't succeed. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
div.text-active
```

CSS selector to represent the first HTML div that you have shared.

and

```
div.text-deactive
```

CSS selector to represent the second HTML div

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `css selector` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.